# InvalidCastException while using .Contains() on a specific column?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am using `List` to find if a column contains the following:

```
List<int> listYear = new List<int>();
for (int i = 1900; i <= 2999; i++ )
{
    listYear.Add(i);
}
```

The above code adds years 1900 up to 2999.

To validate **Year** column if the following cells are Valid, I use this:

```
else if (cboKPI.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Year" && listYear.Contains((int)dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[selected].Value)) {

}
```

But I keep on getting `InvalidCastException`, any fix to this?

Comment: `dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[selected].Value` is probably of type `string`
Check the type of data and either make it use int, either use `Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[selected].Value)` (or similar conversion method) : there are no explicit conversion defined from string to int

Comment: Also, not part of your issue, but using a list containing all years seems overkill:simply check the range, for example

```
bool ValidateYear(int year)
{
    return year >= 1900 && year < 2999;
}
```

Comment: The `Value` property of `DataGridViewCell` is of type `object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having a list of valid numbers, why not validate the actual *data* itself using [`TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) for example?

```
if(cboKPI.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Year")
{
    int year;
    if(!int.TryParse(dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[selected].Value.ToString()), out year) { /* error */ }
    else
    {
        if(year >= 1900 && year < 3000) ...
    }
}
```

Alternativly you can also use `Convert.ToInt32` instead of `TryParse`. However the former will throw an exception if the data within your cell isn´t parsable to int.

```
int year = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[selected].Value=;
```